# Charging balance with 2 batteries: How is kitchen aluminium foil dangerous despite same voltages?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-chemistry

If 2 batteries of the same kind are connected to each other, the battery with more charge, thus higher voltage, will charge the one with less capacity.

A standard NiMH battery charger uses 1.3V to 1.6V of input power to charge the battery.
Let's assume, that one NiMH has 1.3V at the momentary charge, the other one 1.0V.

In the Internet, there were many claims, that using kitchen foil for that purpose is dangerous due to high currents. But how can these high currenrs be achieved despite the voltages are still not out of ordinary?

Comment: Ohms law.......

Comment: Using kitchen foil for what purpose? As a conductor between two batteries? Between a charger and a battery?

Comment: Using Aluminium foil for anything related to electronics is asking for trouble if you ask me. OK, I would be OK with using it around a piece of styrofoam (to short all pins) for shipping DIP ICs in case you do not have the proper ESD-safe foam available.

Comment: Why in the name of pitchforks and pointed ears are you using aluminum foil in any kind of way with your batteries?

Comment: @JRE I did **not use it.** I am just asking

Comment: Kitchen foil for what purpose exactly? Are you wanting to be a candidate for the 2018 edition of the Darwin Awards?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes. I want that award. Jokes aside, you have a good humour. **I did never try it and never ever wanted to. I am just asking.**

Comment: but you don't explain what you are even considering - and this has been pointed out several times - this will eventually cause your questions to be ignored...

Comment: Your aren't using it, but somebody on the internet did, which led to your question.  What were they doing with batteries and aluminum foil and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*But how can these high currents be achieved despite the voltages are still not out of ordinary?*

Because the amount of current which is going to flow depends on **voltage** and **resistance**, we call this [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law).

Consider this 2 battery circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyMv8u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How much current will flow?

The voltage across the resistor is 1.3 - 1.0 = 0.3 V

Divide that by the resistance: I = V/R = 0.3 / 0.1 = 3 A

You might not think 3 A is a lot but this assumes that the total resistance (of both batteries and whatever you use to connect them in parallel) has a resistance of 100 m Ohm. The resistance could be less and that would result in a higher current.

Also 3 A **is** a lot of current for for example an AA cell to flow continously for some time. A few seconds would be OK but not for more than a few minutes as the cell would heat up.

When using Aluminium foil it is impossible to say what the resistance will be. In general NiMh cells do have a very low internal resistance so they will not contribute that much to the **total** resistance.

Edit: According to this interesting [document from Energizer](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/nickelmetalhydride_appman.pdf), page 6: The Internal resistance  of fresh, fully charged NiMH batteries is typically less than 50 milliohms.

Comment: So how do battery chargers charge using 1.6V without needing to increase currents? According to Ohm's law, a serial circuit requires current to keep voltage alive.

Comment: Suppose you take a NiMh battery charger **without a battery in it** and you measure 1.6 V between the contacts, that means that the battery can charge to a maximum of 1.6 V. Not more as no current can then flow. When you place a NiMh cell of say 1.2 V, a current starts to flow. There will be a resistor or some circuit to **limit** the current (not increase it!). That current then charges the cell.